Error in importing Data SQL Server
While importing the data in the SQL Server, I am getting this error.

I am not able to solve the error after trying so much in the internet and youtube also.
Can anyone help in solving me this error.

Are you sure that you have the right database for SQL server , that looks more like data for MySQL

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

1.) First be sure that you are using correct SqlClientData Provider.
You might getting data from MySql and insert into MsSql.
Your data source could be MySql but check it if it is correct due to name similarity. It is probale to missusage.

2.) Your Sql query returning none unique InvariantName values from source for your target table.

Check target table's Primary Key and indexes for unique InvariantName
Select sample list from target table and compare with your source query result.
Then modify your source query to give result with the same pattern of existing records.
Idealy using distinct keyword in select query is not offered but it could help you find for unique results.
